# how to sort data from database in listview using c# and entity framework

Tags: c#, web-services, listview, web-applications, windowsformshost

I'm using Empty Web Application as my host and i have different classes, such as users in it.

I also have a client (Windows Forms app).

**Please notice this is Entity framework database!**

Ok here's the thing. I want to display sorted data **by name** in listview.

In my Empty Web app, i have Webservice where i have the code for displaying users.

**This is the code, and it works**

```
public Users[] getUsers()
    {
        List<Users> userList = new List<Users>();
        using (var db = new DataBase())
        {
            var query = from x in db.userList
                            select new
                            {
                                ID = x.UserID,
                                name = x.Name,
                                lName = x.LastName,
                                age = x.Age,
                                club = x.Club,
                                price = x.Price
                            };
            foreach (var user in query)
            {
                Users usrLst = new Users();
                usrLst.UserID = ID;
                usrLst.Name = user.name;
                usrLst.LastName = user.lName;
                usrLst.Age = user.age;
                usrLst.Club = user.club;
                usrLst.Price = user.price;
                userList.Add(usrLst);
            }
        }
        return userList.ToArray();
```

This displays data from my entitiy framework database to listview in my client (windows forms application).

Can you guys please help me fix this, so it gets sorted **by name**

**I would really appreciate any input!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   var query = from x in db.userList
               orderby x.Name
               select new
               {
                   ID = x.UserID,
                   name = x.Name,
                   lName = x.LastName,
                   age = x.Age,
                   club = x.Club,
                   price = x.Price
               };
```

Answer (score 1):

At the return statement.

instead of `return userList.ToArray();`

Try changing to

```
return userList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but i chose Jose M answer. Thank you very much anyways!